# Why the AFD & Kpss test result is stationary series while ACF plot decaying slowly?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

the ADF result
[image]

and ACF &PACF[image]
[image]

the series decomposition , the seasonality exist . so why the statistical tests stationary
[image]

Comment: The decay is not really slow. A unit root would result in a slower decay.

Comment: What about the seasonality exit in the series decomposition ?